# Mongo equivalent of Spring 'Containing'

Tags: spring, mongodb

In my mongorepository I have a function called:

```
findByParticipantIdsContaining(String participantId);
```

What is the mongo operation used for `Containing`? I thought it'd be something like:

```
Criteria containsParticipantId = where(participantId).in("participantIds");
```

but it's not...

EDIT
I think it may be:

```
Criteria containsParticipantId = where("participantIds").is(participantId);
```

I'll give it a test.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring containing operation looks like a *LIKE* operation in MySQL. In mongo, *LIKE* operator doesn't exist but instead you can use *is* operator as you suggested but with a regex as value